# AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'use_required_attribute'

Tags: django-models, django-forms, attributeerror

I try to add a form-control class to an input field of a model-based form in Django, but I get this error message:

> AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'use_required_attribute'.

How do I fix this?

class in views.py:

```
class TweetCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = TweetSearch
    fields = ['search_term', 'query_type', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'language', 'country']
    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        form.fields['search_term'].widget = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        form.fields['query_type'].widget = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        form.fields['start_date'].widget = DateTimePickerInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        form.fields['end_date'].widget = DateTimePickerInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        form.fields['language'].widget = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})),
        form.fields['country'].widget = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})),
        return form
```

class in models.py:

```
class TweetSearch(models.Model):
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    search_term = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='blue bird')
    QUERY_CHOICES = (
        ('t', 'in tweet'),
        ('h', 'in hashtag'),
        ('u', 'username'),
    )
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, blank=True)
    query_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUERY_CHOICES, blank=True, default='t')
    start_default = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=start_default)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='English')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='USA')
    searcher = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tweet_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Tweets with the word {self.search_term} from {self.start_date} till {self.end_date} written in " \
               f"{self.language} in {self.country}."
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="searchcontainer" style="text-align: center">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.search_term}}
        {{form.query_type}}
        {{form.start_date}}
        {{form.end_date}}
        {{form.language}}
        {{form.country}}
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You are confusing form field with widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing form field with widgets. You should assign a widget like `TextInput`, not a form field like `CharField`, like:

```
class TweetCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = TweetSearch
    fields = ['search_term', 'query_type', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'language', 'country']
    
    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        form.fields['search_term'].widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        form.fields['query_type'].widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        form.fields['start_date'].widget=DateTimePickerInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        form.fields['end_date'].widget=DateTimePickerInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        form.fields['language'].widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        form.fields['country'].widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        return form
```

It however here might be better to just plug in a `ModelForm`, so:

```
class TweetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TweetSearch
        fields = ['search_term', 'query_type', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'language', 'country']
        widgets = {
            'search_term': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'query_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'start_date': DateTimePickerInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'end_date': DateTimePickerInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'language': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'country': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
         }
```

and plug this into the `TweetCreateView`:

```
class TweetCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = TweetSearch
    form_class = TweetForm
```

if you however only want to change the class, you can simplify this with:

```
class FormControlForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'


class TweetForm(FormControlForm, forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = TweetSearch
        fields = ['search_term', 'query_type', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'language', 'country']
```